# open text box which clicking on image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an image on which "click to edit" is written now when i click that part i want to show edit box where "Type 1" is written.

I have tried to put edit box but unable to get the click event ...

here is the image

http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?55dd1b316d.png

Comment: There is an example for doing this in the official jQuery documentation: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Edit_in_Place_with_Ajax

Comment: Can you post example html code, and what javascript code you have so far?

Is your goal to do ajax updates? or hidden input fields that get updated on save? or something else?

Comment: no its just a static text , i am not firing ajax request

Answer (score 1):

i assume you're using jquery

```
$('#yourimageid').bind('click', function(){
    .... your box appearance code here
});
```

if not it's a bit mor letters, but the same thing

```
document.getElementById('yourimageid').onclick = function(){
     .... your box appearance code here
}
```

Comment: Actually, they're not *exactly* the same thing. The former you can run multiple times and it will execute all of the callbacks. The latter will only execute the last one assigned.

Comment: @icktoofay thanks for the addendum. this is for sure neccessary to mention!

Comment: but this code will execute when ever i will click on any part of image i just want to fire click event while user click on "click to edit..." text inside image

Comment: okay then i suggest using image-maps ... and binding the event on that area then.

Comment: @Hunt If you want to have more than one link per image (or a restricted clickable area), it's the same principle.  You'd need to create an image map.  You'd then give each image-map link a separate ID and use helle's method.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#the-image").click(function() {
    // show the edit box
    $("#edit-box").show();
}
```

If it's something simple like that, then just position #edit-box with CSS.